# How can I check if a scroll was done by code or by user?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm currently building a chat. In my chat I've an input. If if type something in my input and press enter, a new message get's added the list get's scrolled down so that the new message is visible and not hidden.

The problem is that I'm doing special things in a scroll event which should only be triggered when the users scrolls down and not my function which adds a new message.

So how can I do this?

I've already tried the `.on( "mousewheel", function () {` but this event get's also triggered if I'm at the end of the list and I still try to scroll down, even if there is nothing to go anymore.

```js
jQuery( document ).ready( function ( $ ) {
 $( "#messages" ).scroll( function () {
  console.log( "Scrolled!" );
 } );

 $( "input" ).keypress( function ( e ) {
  if ( e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey ) {
   $( "#messages" ).scrollTop( $( "#messages" ).prop( "scrollHeight" ) );
   $( "#messages" ).append( "<div class=\"message right\">" + $( this ).val() + "</div>" );
   $( this ).val( "" );
  }
 } );
} );
```

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#messages > div { 
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.date-area {
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.spacer {
  height: 35px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
</div>
<input placeholder="Enter something and press enter key"/>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a condition in `$('#messages').scroll(...)`. Here, I use `scrollCauseByNewMessage` variable to determine what to do when a scroll is caused by entering new messages and when a scroll is caused by actual scrolling.

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  let scrollCauseByNewMessage = false
  $("#messages").scroll(function() {
    if (scrollCauseByNewMessage) {
      scrollCauseByNewMessage = false
      // Do other things
      return
    }
    
    // Do your special scroll function here
    else {
      console.log("Scrolled!");
    }
  });

  $("input").keypress(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13 && !e.shiftKey) {
      scrollCauseByNewMessage = true
      $("#messages").scrollTop($("#messages").prop("scrollHeight"));
      $("#messages").append("<div class=\"message right\">" + $(this).val() + "</div>");
      $(this).val("");
    }
  });
});
```

```css
#messages {
  border: 1px solid;
  max-height: 200px;
  overflow-y: scroll;
}

#messages>div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  padding-left: 3%;
  padding-right: 3%;
}

.message.right {
  text-align: right;
}

.divider span {
  padding: 6px 12px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 1;
  background: gray;
  color: #fff;
  border-radius: 6px;
}

.date-area {
  margin-top: -35px;
}

.spacer {
  height: 35px;
}

input {
  margin-top: 10px;
  width: 100%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="messages">
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message left">Testnachricht</div>
  <div class="message right">Testnachricht</div>
</div>
<input placeholder="Enter something and press enter key" />
```